# Cron and PHP 5.2 - Memory Issues processing JSON

Tags: php, json, memory, loops, cron

I have a Cron for each user of my project executing a php script every 5 minutes that takes about 4 minutes to get executed. I couldnt find a "lighter" way to do it!

But now I'm facing memory problems, because sometimes files get executed in the same "space of time" and it make my virtual memory to go up!

I've tried to make my loops lighter but they are still consuming 25MB for each file!

If you guys have any good solution I would appreciate :). Here it is

```
for($x = 0; $x <= 14; $x++)
{

    $r = rand(0,7);
    $jsonData = $this->getsomejson($value[$r]);
    if ($this->meta->code == 400){continue;}

    foreach ((array)$jsonData->data as $key=>$value)
    {
        $result = doSomething($value->id,$Token[$x]);
        if ($result==200){$L++;}
        $i++;
        unset($value);
    }      

    unset($r,$jsonData,$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know what the code behind "getsomejson" and "doSomething" is it is hard to say what would be the bottleneck here.

If these are 2 pretty simple functions I guess the problem is that you have to load a huge json file and you might try to compress the file.

Otherwise you should give some more detail on the functions "getsomejson" and "doSomething" to see if these can be optimized

Comment: thanks for your reply mate ! My function pull pictures from Instagram API it gets the JSON file and it makes an action for each DATA item incuded in the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

we can set a signal or mark whenever a cron job starts, then we check this signal or mark to see if there is a job running, if yes, stop starting a new job, otherwise, start it.

We can store this signal or mark in a file or a database table

```
$signal = get_it_from_file(); 
if ($signal < max) {
  //start to do our job
   ..............
   $signal = $signal+1;
   store_it_to_file();
} else {
      //skip it
}
```

we can adjust max to control how many jobs run concurrently